# Create and upload PDF to azure blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, pdfkit

I'm using [PDFkit](https://pdfkit.org/) to create a PDF, however I want to upload the created PDF to azure blob storage. I have the below code (typescript) but its not working:

```js
const doc = new PDFDocument();
doc.fontSize(27).text("test", 100, 100);
doc.end();

const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(
      doc,
      Buffer.byteLength(doc)
    );
```

i'm able to connect to the azure blob storage, however the uploading part is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested in my environment

You can use the below code to upload PDF file from PDFKIT to Azure Blob Storage

```
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
const fs = require('fs');
const blobName = "doc.pdf";
const doc = new PDFDocument();
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(blobName));
doc.fontSize(27).text("test", 100, 100);
doc.end();

const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadFile(blobName);
```